# Is possible to add operator a class?

Tags: c#

look the UML image. I've got a generic class called BinaryProblem, this one receives two values of T value, int long, decimal. But I decided add a new one, Fraction class.

[image]

Suppose that I have a method called Add, Substract, Multiplicate and Division. I'd like to do something like this.

```
var a = new Fraction(1 / 2);
var b = new Fraction(3 / 4);
var c = a + b;  // Fraction { Numerator = 5, Denominator = 4 }
```

I know that can only put an condition, if (x.GetType() == ...) but, I'm sure later I'd add another types, and avoid to repeat some code.

I almost forget it, is possible to add numbers where the type is generic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to add the operator + to the `Fraction` type.  If so try the following

```
class Fraction { 
  public static Fraction operator+(Fraction left, Fraction right) {
    return left.Add(right);
  }

  public static Fraction operator+(Fraction left, int right) {
    var right = new Fraction(right);
    return left.Add(right);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but what is `BinaryProblem<T>` doing then?

Comment: @JaredPar wow, how speedy you are! By the way I forgot to write something, is possible to add numbers where the value type is T?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart not sure. Was waiting for the OP to correct me on how it related to the problem.  The code sample though seemed to call directly for this.

Comment: BinaryProblem<T> is just a class where does arithmetic operations like +,-,*, or /

Comment: @DarfZon only if `T` is a concrete type like `int` or is a type parameter on the type `Fraction` (or a parent type).  Operators can't be themselves generic.

Comment: well, the intention of the class is for data types values like numbers (int, long, decimal, double.. of course not string or even bool)

Comment: @DarfZon could you give us some example code that you want to use?

Comment: this is not the real code, but it something like this: public T Add()
        {
            return Number1 + Number2;
        }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6911/discussion-between-darf-zon-and-jaredpar)